# ARCore sdk, hello_ar_kotlin sample failed to build on android studio 2022.3.1 canary 8 with the error "PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9"?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, arcore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCy4o.png)i tried to use ARCore sdk on android studio canary 8 , however when i try to open the "hello_ar_kotlin" sample the build fails immediatly  and i get "PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9" error .

i tried to sync the project many times and tried to update the minSdkVersion to 33 also the targetSdkVersion  to 33 but didn't work.